# How to force dev unlock of Windows Phone 8 device?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Surprisingly, after May 14, 2015 Microsoft has said that Windows Phone 8 devices will no longer be developer unlocked due to MS security certificates expiring. This date has obviously come and gone, nonetheless here I am with an HTC Windows Phone 8S, a phone that won't receive 8.1 update but in need of some developer testing. Does anyone know of a way around this to developer unlock a phone? I've tried changing the date back to pre-May 14, however, this does not work.

[image: Windows Phone 8 Developer Unlock Error 0x64]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't unlock it as a Windows Phone 8.0 device, but you can upgrade it to Windows Phone 8.1 through the [Windows Phone Developer Preview](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/devpreview) and then developer unlock it.

While early versions of the Windows Phone 8.1 preview did not support the 8s, the update has been available for that device since September (see http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2014/09/24/new-update-for-windows-phone-preview-for-developers/ )

Comment: As stated in original post, HTC Windows Phone 8S will not upgraded to 8.1. Therefore I have a brick phone since the only use of this phone was for testing. As a developer who paid $99 for a dev license, for some reason I expected more. As a developer for both MS and Android, it is painful to see MS make it so hard for developers when Android never has this sort of problem.

Comment: You can install the OS Preview app for developers on your phone to use your developer credentials to force the update to 8.1. You can get the app at https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/preview-for-developers/178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96. The program is detailed here: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/devpreview. Rolling back the date/time on your phone won't work since the unlock process checks the local time vs the server time and they have to match (it's certificates 101).

Comment: The statement added to the original post is out of date. I edited my answer to clarify.